# MaterialUI how to align text inside an Input to the right or center?

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

How to align text of a Material UI input text? Following does not seem to work. Im using version 1.x

```
import {Input} from 'material-ui';

//didn't work
<Input
   className="max-w-128 inline-block"
   style = {{textAlign: 'center'}}
   id="input-quantity"
   inputStyle={{ textAlign: 'center' }}
   //tried hintStyle as suggested in a bug
   hintStyle={{ width: '600px', textAlign: 'center' }}
   value={this.state.currentRecord.quantity}
   onChange={this.handleCurrentRecordTextChange('quantity')}
/>
```

Comment: is it even possible? couldn't find any material regarding this.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/n4xm59xovj

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you just need to use (with styles overriding) :

```
classes={{
 input: classes.inputCenter
}}
```

and the styles should be:

```
const styles = theme => ({
  inputCenter: {
    textAlign: "center",
    color: "red"
  }
});
```

go through the documentation from here: https://material-ui.com/api/input/#css-api

here is a working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/n9nr9x8xo0

hope this will help you.

Comment: Thank u! Helped me a lot

Comment: Thank you very much for pointing out. I fixed the dependency issues. please check.

Answer (score 5):

Please Use

```
<Typography align="centre|right" />
```

If you have specific font already set then use above solution with withStyle HOC